# R - Extract all elements of a list with name X

Tags: r

I would like to know if it possible to subset named elements of a list that are stored in different branches of the list but have the same level and same name.

I store my data this way:
list
-related result
-habitat
-Terrestrial
-Interaction
-Abundance
-Marine
-Interaction
-Abundance

This is just an example but as you can see, once you access to "habitat", the tables stored into each habitats have the same name.

What if I want to return a list that contain each Abundance tables? How would you extract that all at once without a loop?

So far I managed to select the 4 habitats by names.

```
str(ready.for.RLQ[parameters$habitat], max.level = 2)
```

Where parameters$habitat contains the names of the habitats (Fucus, Sand, Rock, Zostera).

I am trying to get to the next level and extract for instance all the Q tables (see below) and extract a list that contains those tables.
I always had a bit of troubles moving around list.

Thanks in advance

[image: The structure of the list]

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to demonstrate without having access to your actual data, but suppose we had a list like this:

```r
my_list <- list(first = list(a = 1, b = 2), second = list(a = 3, b = 4))
str(my_list)
#> List of 2
#>  $ first :List of 2
#>   ..$ a: num 1
#>   ..$ b: num 2
#>  $ second:List of 2
#>   ..$ a: num 3
#>   ..$ b: num 4
```

Then we can create a list of only the object `a` using `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) x$a)
#> $first
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $second
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I missed your answer. What if the list goes deeper?
How would one select the elements?
x$a$el1?